# Disable rails 3 default routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a rails application and I dont need certain routes. for example the user will not be able to create a new "Product". In fact nobody will since those products are read from a file only. so how can I remove the 'products/new' route? should I replace the code in the products controller? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably shouldn't have `new`, `create` or other record-altering methods in the ProductsController, since they're not going to get used, but the actual way to specify which routes exist is in the `config/routes.rb` file. Typically, you'd have a line in there something like:

```
resources :products
```

This provides the basic RESTful routes for products. You can, however, specify that only some of the routes should exist:

```
resources :products, :except => [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

Or:

```
resources :products, :only => [:index, :show]
```